# Setting Speed and Duplex to Auto disconnects Internet on Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a newly purchased D-link DIR - 819, router. My Internet Connection is Static IP. I have set the Settings as provided by my ISP. My Internet connection is of 60 Mbps. However. the router only works when I set the WAN port speed to 10 Mbps. Setting it to 100 Mbps, or Auto causes router to constantly connect and disconnect to the Internet. It connects and disconnects by the second. However, if I connect the Ethernet cable directly to the Desktop, and set the Speed and Duplex to Auto, the Ethernet connects and disconnects a few times, then it works fine for however long I use it. Here are a few things to note -

- I have set the same MAC address of both the Desktop and the router.
- If I leave the router on Auto for 7-8 hours, then I get a stable Internet connection for a few hours, before it starts connecting and disconnecting again.
- I tried another old TP-Link router, it had the same problem.
- MTU size,and every other settings are identical on both Desktop and Router.
- I am using the latest non-Beta firmware on the router.

Where is the problem ?

Comment: What device does the cable from router's "WAN" port connect to? How old is the cable itself, was it pre-made with connectors or did you make it yourself?

Comment: Try an alternate cable.

Comment: user1686 I think it's connected to the Modem or a Switch that the ISP provided. I don't have access to it as it's fixed on top of a Pole on the Street.

Comment: davidgo Sadly I don't think that's possible because the ISP provided the cable, and to change that I have to talk to them. Which I'm sure they won't